# express test router app.use("v1/books", bookRouter)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, integration-testing

I am not sure about how to test my booksRouter.
Instead of repeating in the router "/v1/books" in front of each route, I'm using the convenient following syntax

```js
app.use("v1/books", booksRouter);
```

But since there is no prefix anymore in my router, I am not sure about how to test the full route path.

Here is an extract from my app.ts

```js
import express from "express";
import booksRouter from "./books.router";

const app = express();
app.use("v1/books", booksRouter);

export default app;
```

And here is an extract from my router test file

```js
import request from "supertest";
import app from "../app";
import bookRouter from "../books.router";
import BookController from "../controllers/book.controller";

describe("GET /:id", () => {
  it("should return book from an existing id", async () => {
    const newBook = await BookController.createBook({
      price: 100,
      title: "Great book",
    });
    //HERE IS THE ROUTE : /myBookId
    //But in fact it's /v1/books/myBookId
    const response = await request(app).get(`/${newBook._id}`);
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
    expect(newBook._id.equals(response.body._id)).toBe(true);
    expect(response.body.price).toEqual(newBook.price);
    expect(response.body.title).toEqual(newBook.title);
  });
});
```

One of my solution is to add the prefix in each test but I don't want to have a strong coupling here.

What do you think ? I have the feeling that it's a mix between unit and integration testing